# Creating a custom key which is filterable, reversible and decryptable? In Python

Tags: python, hash, key

My task is to create a custom key or digital signature. This key will be created from attributes from a record. Each record in my table corresponds to a custom key, and each custom key will be comprised of certain attributes from that record. The purpose of this key is for tracking changes, and comparing keys to view the differences and similarities.

For example, `01|11|00|10` --> each 2 digits represent a specific value of and attribute. In this key there are 4 attributes, so 4 values for each 4 attributes.

My solution is to create a switch statement or something similar and manually defined the attributes and values.
But I am pretty sure there is a much better and optimal solution than this like using bits or hex to represent each attribute.
Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4*4*4*4 (256) possible combinations. You can view your key as an 8-bit byte. Consider, given 8 bits:

```
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
--- --- --- ---
 |   |   |   |
 |   |   |   attribute1
 |   |   attribute2
 |   attribute3
 attribute4
```

Each of the attributes can have four values. To pack those four attribute values into a single byte, you can write:

```
key = (attr4 << 6) | (attr3 << 4) | (attr2 << 2) | attr1;
```

The `<<` operator does a "left shift", shifting bits in the quantity to the left. So, imagine you have:

```
attr4 = 3  // 11
attr3 = 2  // 10
attr2 = 3  // 11
attr1 = 1  // 01
```

First, we compute `(attr4 << 6)`. That gives us `11000000`. That is, we start with `00000011` and shift the bits left six times.

Then `(attr3 << 4)` gives us `00100000`. `(attr2 << 2)` produces `00001100`. Then, we combine them with the bitwise OR operator:

```
11000000 | 00100000 | 00001100 | 00000001
```

Or perhaps it's easier to view this way:

```
11000000
00100000
00001100
00000001
--------
11101101 -- Key
```

The result of bitwise OR is to put a `1` in any position that contains a `1` in any of the values.

And to reverse it you write:

```
attr1 = (key & 3);
attr2 = (key >> 2) & 3;
attr3 = (key >> 4) & 3;
attr4 = (key >> 6) & 3;
```

Reversing it is a matter of shifting the bits you're interested in to the first two positions (bits 0 and 1), and then masking them off with a bitwise AND. For example, given the key value of `11101101`, you want to extract `attr3`. So you shift it right by 4 positions to produce `00001110`. The bits for `attr3` are in the first two positions, and the bits for `attr4` are in the next two. Then, mask it by doing a bitwise AND with 3:

```
00001101 & 00000011
```

The result of ANDing a value is 1 if both values contain a 1 in that bit position. So position 0 has a 1 in both values. Position 2 has a 0 in the attribute. So the result is `01`.

This isn't encryption, by the way, but rather encoding.